# Google App Engine Deploying Issue

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, terminal, zshrc

My terminal's showing this two lines,

`/Users/dean/.zshrc:source:89: no such file or directory: /Users/dean/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc`

---

`/Users/dean/.zshrc:source:92: no such file or directory: /Users/dean/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc`

What does it mean and how should I fix it? And I can't deploy in GAE Launcher.

Comment: try another shell, your zsh seems to be broken

Comment: Yeah, I just uninstalled zsh and back to bash. Those lines are gone, but GAE still is not working.

Comment: please update question with new error lines

Comment: Please check [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/czoziux5tqw3gc4/Screenshot%202016-07-05%2016.27.08.png?dl=0) out. That's the newly-created project, doesn't relate to the old/previous ones. Here's my (old/previous) another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068253/deploying-first-app-gae?noredirect=1#comment63601941_38068253) about it. However, the error is the same. **You do not have permission** in Launcher, although I can deploy via Terminal.